# varnish redirecting to backend url

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, varnish, magento

Im running Magento in 192.169.1.250 (no ssl) URL - http://192.168.1.250:80
and varnish + nginx (ssl offloading) in 192.168.1.9
frontend URL - https://192.168.1.9:80
varnish 127.0.0.1:6081

Used the default varnish default.vcl file generated by Magento backoffice no changes in Magento Nginx config too.

But when I access https://192.168.1.9 the url is redirected to https://192.168.1.250. But I can access the magento storefront with http://192.168.1.250 no issues

let me know if any other details req

varnish log

> - << BeReq    >> 32784

- Begin          bereq 32783 fetch
- Timestamp      Start: 1594988018.618675 0.000000 0.000000
- BereqMethod    GET
- BereqURL       /
- BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
- BereqHeader    Host: 192.168.1.9:6081
- BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
- BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36 Edg/83.0.478.64
- BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
- BereqHeader    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
- BereqHeader    Cookie: PHPSESSID=dde5bhbam76djce6pfn587is5r
- BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.1.7
- BereqHeader    grace: none
- BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
- BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 32784
- VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
- VCL_return     fetch
- BackendOpen    26 boot.default 192.168.1.250 80 192.168.1.9 57404
- BackendStart   192.168.1.250 80
- Timestamp      Bereq: 1594988018.618732 0.000057 0.000057
- Timestamp      Beresp: 1594988018.760098 0.141424 0.141367
- BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
- BerespStatus   302
- BerespReason   Found
- BerespHeader   Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
- BerespHeader   Date: Fri, 17 Jul 2020 12:13:38 GMT
- BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
- BerespHeader   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
- BerespHeader   Connection: keep-alive
- BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=dde5bhbam76djce6pfn587is5r; expires=Fri, 17-Jul-2020 13:13:38 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=192.168.1.9; HttpOnly
- BerespHeader   Location: http://192.168.1.250/
- BerespHeader   Pragma: no-cache
- BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
- BerespHeader   Expires: Wed, 17 Jul 2019 12:13:38 GMT
- BerespHeader   Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; form-action geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcomme
- BerespHeader   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
- BerespHeader   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
- BerespHeader   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
- BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
- BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
- TTL            RFC 0 10 0 1594988019 1594988019 1594988018 1563365618 0
- VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
- TTL            VCL 0 259200 0 1594988019
- TTL            VCL 0 259200 0 1594988019
- VCL_return     deliver
- BerespUnset    Content-Encoding: gzip
- BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
- Storage        malloc Transient
- ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
- ObjStatus      302
- ObjReason      Found
- ObjHeader      Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
- ObjHeader      Date: Fri, 17 Jul 2020 12:13:38 GMT
- ObjHeader      Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
- ObjHeader      Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=dde5bhbam76djce6pfn587is5r; expires=Fri, 17-Jul-2020 13:13:38 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=192.168.1.9; HttpOnly
- ObjHeader      Location: http://192.168.1.250/
- ObjHeader      Pragma: no-cache
- ObjHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
- ObjHeader      Expires: Wed, 17 Jul 2019 12:13:38 GMT
- ObjHeader      Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; form-action geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcomme
- ObjHeader      X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
- ObjHeader      X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
- ObjHeader      X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
- ObjHeader      Vary: Accept-Encoding
- ObjHeader      Content-Encoding: gzip
- Fetch_Body     2 chunked -
- Gzip           G F E 0 20 80 80 90
- Gzip           U F - 20 0 80 80 90
- BackendReuse   26 boot.default
- Timestamp      BerespBody: 1594988018.760240 0.141566 0.000142
- Length         20
- BereqAcct      514 0 514 2553 0 2553
- End

- << Request  >> 32783

- Begin          req 32782 rxreq
- Timestamp      Start: 1594988018.618581 0.000000 0.000000
- Timestamp      Req: 1594988018.618581 0.000000 0.000000
- ReqStart       192.168.1.7 53361
- ReqMethod      GET
- ReqURL         /
- ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
- ReqHeader      Host: 192.168.1.9:6081
- ReqHeader      Connection: keep-alive
- ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
- ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36 Edg/83.0.478.64
- ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
- ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
- ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
- ReqHeader      Cookie: PHPSESSID=dde5bhbam76djce6pfn587is5r
- ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.1.7
- VCL_call       RECV
- ReqHeader      grace: none
- ReqURL         /
- ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
- ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
- VCL_return     hash
- VCL_call       HASH
- VCL_return     lookup
- VCL_call       MISS
- VCL_return     fetch
- Link           bereq 32784 fetch
- Timestamp      Fetch: 1594988018.760291 0.141710 0.141710
- RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
- RespStatus     302
- RespReason     Found
- RespHeader     Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
- RespHeader     Date: Fri, 17 Jul 2020 12:13:38 GMT
- RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
- RespHeader     Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=dde5bhbam76djce6pfn587is5r; expires=Fri, 17-Jul-2020 13:13:38 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=192.168.1.9; HttpOnly
- RespHeader     Location: http://192.168.1.250/
- RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
- RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
- RespHeader     Expires: Wed, 17 Jul 2019 12:13:38 GMT
- RespHeader     Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; form-action geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcomme
- RespHeader     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
- RespHeader     X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
- RespHeader     X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
- RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
- RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
- RespHeader     X-Varnish: 32783
- RespHeader     Age: 0
- RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
- VCL_call       DELIVER
- RespUnset      Age: 0
- RespUnset      Pragma: no-cache
- RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
- RespUnset      Expires: Wed, 17 Jul 2019 12:13:38 GMT
- RespHeader     Expires: -1
- RespUnset      Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
- RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
- RespUnset      Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
- RespUnset      X-Varnish: 32783
- RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
- VCL_return     deliver
- Timestamp      Process: 1594988018.760308 0.141727 0.000017
- RespHeader     Content-Length: 20
- RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
- Timestamp      Resp: 1594988018.760327 0.141746 0.000019
- ReqAcct        486 0 486 2487 20 2507
- End

- << Session  >> 10

- Begin          sess 0 HTTP/1
- SessOpen       192.168.1.7 53362 a0 192.168.1.9 6081 1594988018.610281 22
- SessClose      RX_TIMEOUT 5.006
- End

- << Session  >> 32782

- Begin          sess 0 HTTP/1
- SessOpen       192.168.1.7 53361 a0 192.168.1.9 6081 1594988018.609999 23
- Link           req 32783 rxreq
- SessClose      RX_TIMEOUT 5.152
- End

Answer (score 0):

Lol problem fixed it the Magento which is redirecting changed settings in BackOffice - auto-redirect base URL to no. this fixed the 302 redirect
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ym8n.png)